# Emacs in Ubuntu Terminal: Meta key opens menus

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I've been learning Emacs in fullscreen -nw mode (terminal) for Ubuntu, and I've run into this annoying problem. Whenever I press LAlt-[chr] where chr is some character, if that key combination happens to be the shortcut for one of the terminal menus at the top of the screen, the menu will open and nothing will happen in Emacs. How can I prevent these key combinations from influencing the menu bar?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should be able to disable menu activation by unchecking the correspoding box in the shortcut dialog under Edit.

Right-click on the emulator window to make the menubar visible, if it is not visible.

As I am a debian user I'm not sure if this solution still works in ubuntu at least in version 2.30.2 of gnome-terminal it was possible to change it this way.

Unfortunately the gnome guys seem to to be uninventing the ui so fast, that I'm not sure if it is still possible.

Comment: How is it on Debian? I've been trying to figure out whether to switch to a different distro, but I haven't found any reasons to do so.

Comment: In my opinion debian is one of the best GNU/Linux distributions for a whole couple of reasons.

Comment: I like the packaging system and the fact that it's  driven by the community. Its my impression this adds to slightly better quality. It's definately not the right distribution if you want to be on the bleeding edge, or have newer hardware - beeing tired of continusly applying kernel patches and installing kernel modules from external sources for unsupported harware coponents I switched to ubuntu for a couple of years and have just returned home with the last debian release.

Answer (score 17):

In ubuntu 12.04 for gnome terminal:

Go to `Edit -> Keyboard shortcuts...` and uncheck `Enable menu access keys (such as Alt-F to open the File menu)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Xubuntu 18.04 for Xfce Terminal:

1. `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Advanced`
2. Check `Disable all menu access keys (such as Alt-f)`